# Assigning a string variable to the space character " " in order to find repeated words

Tags: c++, string

```
int main()
{
    std::string previous = " ";
    std::string current;

    while (std::cin >> current)
    {
        if (previous == current)
            std::cout << "\n repeated word: " << current;
        previous = current;
    }
};
```

The program works, but I don't know why. What exactly is the computer doing here? From what I understand, the computer first reads user input then checks if the word matches with "previous" which is initialized to a space character. Is the computer checking if both string variables are space characters? At what point does previous take on a different value?

Answer (score 0):

In every step of the loop, `current` is checked against `previous`, and then `previous` is assigned to the value of `current` (in the last statement of the loop). Then another word is read into `current`, and so on.

Comment: I can understand that, thanks! I was under the assumption that due to the _if_ statement,  _previous_ would be assigned the value of _current_ **only** if they were both equal. I see that would be the case if they were confined under { }. I see my mistake, thanks again!   btw: how did you format your words with the gray highlight? I'm still getting used to this site.

Comment: @itchimatcha WRT formatting, you can format text as inline code (the grey background) by surrounding it with backticks (`). See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the additional details/documentation.